# How can I extract multiple .CSV files from an API and merge them into one .CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

I am trying to merge outputs from an API into one comprehensive CSV (or Excel) file.  The API has parameters named `start_pub_date` and `end_pub_date` that allow me to capture data over 90-day windows. Entering a URL like this one
`https://www.metricsfornews.com/app/api.php?propertyid=[propertyid]&apitype=articledata&key=[keygoeshere]&start_pub_date=2021-04-01&end_pub_date=2021-06-30&include_metrics=1&format=csv`

will get me the data I need from April 1, 2021 through June 30, 2021. As in, going to that URL outputs a CSV file. However, the API only allows capturing data in 90-day windows.

How can I access that API multiple times for multiple date ranges and output the results to one CSV file? I have seen results for doing this when you already have the CSV file in hand, but not for scenarios where the URL itself outputs a CSV file. Apologies if I'm explaining this badly.

Comment: How does the CSV look? What's stopping you from calling it twice and writing 2 lots of results, one after the other, to the same file?

Comment: @MarkSetchell That sounds like a good idea but I do not know how to do that in Python.